# How can I select the rows on dataframe where specific column are different from each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this example of pandas dataframe:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| ciao | type1 |
| anna | type1 |
| anna | type2 |

I would run a query on this dataframe to get all rows that are different on the column C2, but are equal on the column C1. In this specific example, I would like to get this table:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| anna | type1 |
| anna | type2 |

Is it possible? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `groupby` and `nunique`

```
out = df.groupby('C1').filter(lambda x : any((len(x)>1) & (len(x) == x.nunique())))
Out[167]: 
     C1     C2
1  anna  type1
2  anna  type2
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer...But I have a big problem..I don't know why with this csv (https://ufile.io/xb83mgop) your code doesn't work. Can you help to understand why?